# Problem with Posting JSON object with WSRequest

Tags: web-services, json, playframework

I want Play to call a webservice. The webservice accepts `application/json` and returns this as well. With the following code I'm trying to achieve this. (Note, the `headers.put(xxx)` are added later in an effort to solve the problem).

```
WSRequest request = WS.url(targetURL);
request.body = new Gson().toJson(user);
request.headers.put("Content-type","application/json");
request.headers.put("Accept","application/json");
request.post();
```

The strange thing is that my JBOSS server replies: "Cannot consume content type". If I use my 'Simple REST client' plugin in my Chrome browser, and provide the entire JSON Body GSon created and add the content-type header, I get a valid response. Is this not the way to send JSON to the server? Or am I missing some fundamental piece here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While checking the API documentation on the WSRequest class i noticed the field mime-type
By setting it as follows JBOSS (resteasy) accepted my request succesfully.

```
request.mimeType = "application/json";
```